# How can I get a route to have delay rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I get the route to delay rendering? After `<Link>` is clicked, it will only be rendered after 2 seconds instead of instantly as in react-router-dom.

Comment: What did you try ? Which version of react-router ?

Comment: @ChrisR, it is v4 of react-router-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a set timeout in your componentDidMount to set render state. When render is `false` you return `null` in your render function, if it's true, you render your content

```
class TestComp extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            render: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setSTate({render: true})
        }, 2000)
    }



  render() {

    if(!this.state.render) return null

    return (
      <div>
        Page content
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As for your question about only delaying the render on the first load, you could try adding a query string to tell the component if it needs to delay or not:

```
class TestComp extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        render: this.props.location.delayLoad ? false : true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    if(!this.state.render){
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({render: true}, () => {

            // in the callback, update your query string
            history.push({
              pathname: '/route',
              search: '?delayLoad=false'
            })

          })
      }, 2000)
    }

  }



  render() {

    if(!this.state.render) return null

    return (
      <div>
        Page content
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyway i can disable this when the page is refreshed? The delay only apply when hyperlink is clicked, not when page is load or refreshed

Comment: The only way I can think of is prepending a query string to the URL of the hyper link. e.g. `example.com/route?delayLoad=true` then in the timeout call back, you remove the query / set delayLoad to false. You would then then need to check if `delayLoad` is true or false in your component and set state accordingly.

Comment: @davidlee have added an extended example for you which does the above (I haven't tested it but you should get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question:
**How can i get the route to delay rendering?**

-> I would use a `setTimeout` function inside the [`render`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) property of the `Route`.

Then, to answer your additional conditions stated in comments (that only path accessed from Links should be delayed):

-> I would follow @Stretch0 advice to use a parameter. This parameter should then be tested in the `render` function of the `Route`.